# Ember .save() only saving one attribute

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to create and save a model in Ember but only the first entry in my form is saving leaving the others blank.

Before saving all of the models attributes are correct. (shown with logs)

Any help greatly appreciated!

My Model is:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  endpoint: DS.attr('string'),
  playerVersion: DS.attr('string'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date')
});
```

My Route is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('account');
    }
});
```

My Controller is:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
        actions: {
            save: function() {
                    var _this = this;
                    var model = this.get('model');

                    console.log(model.get('endpoint')); //Shows correct endpoint
                    console.log(model.get('playerVersion')); //Shows correct playerVersion

                    model.save().then(function(account) {

                        console.log(model.get('endpoint')); //Shows correct endpoint
                        console.log(model.get('playerVersion')); //Shows nothing

                        _this.transitionToRoute('accounts.index');
                    });
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you check in browser developer tools what is sent with POST request to your backend? Maybe it's not saved in your backend and frontend is ok. Are you sure you have field in your database for `playerVersion`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Nothing is sent in POST request for the playerVersion field, endpoint is correct.

Comment: You sure nothing is sent for `playerVersion`? In Chrome when you click preview you will get response instead of request values. So, if you could check if both request and response object is correct. If nothing is sent for `playerVersion` then you probably have something other than: `playerVersion: DS.attr('string')`, because it will send `playerVersion: null` with POST request even if it's blank, but declared attribute.

Comment: I have looked in Chrome Network and checked, appologies I might not have been clear before. "playerVersion": "" is being sent as a request, but it should have something in it which was filled out on the form.

Comment: Okay, could you share example value for `playerVersion`?

Comment: So when filling out the form in the new template, I fill out endpoint as dev.something.com and playerVersion as 1.4.0  

endpoint is saved, but playerVersion isn't sent as part of the POST request, you can see in the code that it doesn't log as soon as save is called, whereas endpoint does. 

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, really appreciate your help.

EDIT - I can also see the logs from the server it's making the request to and see a blank entry for playerVersion

Comment: I've create JSBin demo for you, and it works fine: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zomaqimiwo/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I have a custom adapter and serializer on my project, could it be this thats causing the problems? I see no other differences between the JSBin and what I've been doing. It is this https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api

Comment: Yes, probably it's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - Was some settings needed on the custom Serializer needed.

```
export default JsonApiSerializer.extend({
    keyForAttribute: function(key) {
        //return Ember.String.dasherize(key);
        return Ember.String.camelize(key);
    },
    keyForRelationship: function(key) {
        //return Ember.String.dasherize(key);
        return Ember.String.camelize(key);
    },
    keyForSnapshot: function(snapshot) {
        //return Ember.String.dasherize(snapshot.typeKey);
        return Ember.String.camelize(snapshot.typeKey);
    },
});
```